# Can I deploy a fab bundle on any OSGI-compliant container/application server?

Tags: osgi, web-deployment, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am currently trying to deploy my camel app as a FAB bundle in the Fuse ESB container. I understand that I can install Fab(Fabric-bundle) as a feature on OSGI containers like Karaf or felix and deploy the bundle. I want to know if this feature is available on all OSGI containers as well as other application servers like IBM Websphere([Websphere supports OSGI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1007_robinson/1007_robinson.html#sec1)) or will this tie me up to the Fuse ecosystem.

Will deploying as a WAR or an OSGI bundle be a better approach as the goal is to support as many ESB Containers/Application Servers as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is a specialty of Fuse, for this it'll only work on the FUSE containers. Even Vanilla Karaf doesn't understand FAB (unless it's a standard Karaf feature, with just another name to it)

For usage of Karaf Featurs outside of Karaf you'd need to add the feature resolver and services of Karaf to the other OSGi containers first. Never tried that but might be possible.

Comment: FAB can run on Karaf, eg Fuse is running on top of Karaf.